# How to set boundary for mutipart /form data with rest template

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have below code where I have to set boundary with mutipart for data in content type. How can I do that?

```
HttpHeaders theMultipartHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
theMultipartHeaders.set("Authorization","eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ5UUpvYndpVUExdld5SnEyZlJacDRHOExNeWFkRnZ1cjdoR1wvSnllOHdDQmh3YkdBMEoyanA0eGdNT1R1K1wvdUt4MDF6RUwxXC9UYUlqaXRFcTNDUjk3NXFiWWdQc2dVbEdpc2pRT0lndmdNQW1iaVdkUFl4RjhRPT0iLCJuYmYiOjE1NzUyODc1MjIsImlzcyI6InNlc3NlcmkwMzQ1OS5zcy5zdy5lcmljc3Nvbi5zZSIsImV4cCI6MTU3NTI5MTI0MiwiX2NhY2hlSWQiOjEyNDgyNSwiaWF0IjoxNTc1Mjg3NjQyLCJqdGkiOiJJREdBQUZXSUhSU1IxQVFCVlZRQ1FBWUVQQ1k5TlQifQ.4QnMtc9fLttTyZul5t9ao5XOb2COMNlG8zCDZt2CRO0");
theMultipartHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE);
theMultipartHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE);
```

Comment: Refer to the this linke [https://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/mylibrary-files-api/file-add-multipart-post.html]

Comment: [Check Here] https://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/mylibrary-files-api/file-add-multipart-post.html

Comment: I am able to access the url but seems like the page is not there.getting this Looks like Ted misplaced another page. Typical. if you have the code handy, can you please put here. i need to set boundary with content type

Comment: I need somthing like this theMultipartHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE , Boundary = "---abc").